# What is an efficient container for a single reference?

Tags: python, list

I have a list containing arbitrary objects of uniform type:

```
items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

I'm scanning through the list and marking the objects by placing them in a container based on some unimportant condition. Let's say it's odd indices:

```
for i in range(len(items)):
    if i % 2:
        items[i] = (items[i],)
```

A second pass will filter the list to unwrap the flagged items and remove everything else:

```
items = [x[0] for x in items if isinstance(x, tuple)]
```

This code is fundamentally functional. However, for very large arrays, the flagging is increasing memory usage and naturally taking time.

What is the most efficient container to use for something like this? I'm using tuple because it has the smallest footprint of all the container classes I looked at. Is there a better way to wrap a single reference?

Comment: Is it not possible to directly filter from the list instead of first creating a container and filtering based on that?

Comment: @Austin. No. The markup happens in a separate operation. Imagine going through a bunch of other data and checking if it's contained in this list or something like that. Basically, I can't filter until all the visits are done, so I do in fact need two passes.

Comment: It seems strange to do this in two passes. Combining the condition check and the comprehension into a single pass would eliminate the need for any wrapper objects at all.

Comment: Alternatively, for even better memory performance (at the expense of greater interpreter overhead), shift elements directly into their final location and then delete the extra space left over at the end, like the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) does in C++.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica. This is a representation of the actual situation. I have completely external reasons for doing it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using wrapper objects for this is inherently memory-inefficient, since each wrapper will take at least 40 bytes on a 64-bit system - 8 bytes each for

- the type pointer,
- the refcount,
- the content pointer, and
- two pointers needed for CPython's GC system.

This 40-byte minimum is achievable with a custom container:

```
class Wrapper(object):
    __slots__ = ('content',)
    def __init__(self, content):
        self.content = content
```

or with `types.CellType` on Python 3.8+:

```
import types
wrapper = types.CellType(wrapped)
extracted_content = wrapper.cell_contents
```

or with a less direct means of creating closure cells on Python versions below 3.8:

```
def make_wrapper(x):
    return (lambda: x).__closure__[0]

wrapper = make_wrapper(wrapped)
extracted_content = wrapper.cell_contents
```

but techniques that don't involve a wrapper will be able to achieve much lower memory overhead.

Comment: Looks like we're back to storing a list or numpy array of bools.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend a Boolean list or tuple for the marking.  If needed, you could compress this to a bitmap.

```
flag = [i%2 for i in range(len(items))]
```

On the second pass extract the needed elements from `items`:

```
new_items = [x for x, wanted in zip(items, flag) if wanted]
```

Will that move you along?

Comment: I think that is pretty good. Perhaps even using a numpy array to compress further would work. I did edit the last loop. I'll let this hang out for a bit in case someone has a radically different idea, but it looks good to me.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  Numpy is also a good idea, if that's convenient for the items base type.

Comment: It's not convenient for the base type, but the boolean array is totally independent of that.